# jquery .on is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using `$(document).on('ready', function(){////})` nothing is happens so I changed to `$(document).ready(function(){////})`.

When using .on function its not working and throwing error and exeption as follows:

> Warning:
>
> jQuery.Deferred exception: tabs[i].on is not a function TypeError:
>   tabs[i].on is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (https://animesh.dev/wp-content/plugins/hyparticles/assests/script.js?ver=4.9.1:7:11)
>       at j (https://animesh.dev/wp-content/plugins/hyparticles/assests/jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=4.9.1:2:29999)
>       at k (https://animesh.dev/wp-content/plugins/hyparticles/assests/jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=4.9.1:2:30313)
>   undefined
>
> Error:
>
> Uncaught TypeError: tabs[i].on is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (script.js?ver=4.9.1:7)
>       at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=4.9.1:2)
>       at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=4.9.1:2)

note: tabs is a variable defined by me inside script.js

note: I'm using jquery v3.2.1(latest) in minify version

why the error coming out

My script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("ready");
    var tabs = $("ul.nav-tabs > li");

    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].on("click", switchTab);
    }

    function switchTab(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
    }

});
```

Comment: Use var tabs = $("ul.nav-tabs > li").toArray();

Comment: You dont need to use a loop.
 $("ul.nav-tabs > li").on("click",switchTab)

Comment: Why are you doing this in a loop in the first place?  Just do: `$("ul.nav-tabs > li").on("click", switchTab);`

Comment: no bro, the problem is .on is not working even see the first paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what is the issue with this

```
tabs[i].on("click", switchTab);
```

In this case you are using bracket notation which is short for jQuery's `tabs.get(i)`. The [`get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method returns the DOM object, it does not return an jQuery object. Since DOM does not have [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) it throws an error.

So how can you fix it? You could use eq() which returns a jQuery object

```
tabs.eq(i).on("click", switchTab);
```

BUT why loop over the elements yourself when jQuery does it for you.

```
tabs.on("click", switchTab);
```

Comment: thanks this totally give me both the elements to switch the tab

Answer (score 4):

The error is pointing to this:

```
tabs[i].on(...
```

Not the use on the `document.ready` event.

Because `.on()` is a function on the jQuery object, not on any HTML element in JavaScript.  And when you loop through the results of a jQuery object, HTML elements are exactly what you're getting.

You don't need to loop in the first place.  You already *have* a jQuery object:

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li")
```

You can simply call `.on()` on that object:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.nav-tabs > li").on("click", switchTab);

    function switchTab(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
    }

});
```

Comment: but the problem with your answer is i cannot loop with 2 li element

Comment: @AnimeshSahu: It's not clear what you mean by that.  In what way is that a problem?  What isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

`$(document).on('ready')` is removed from `jQuery 3.0` https://api.jquery.com/ready/

> There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0.

Comment: let me check the reference!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the for loop:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tabs = $("ul.nav-tabs > li");

    tabs.on('click', switchTab)

    function switchTab(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
    }

});
```

Comment: the problem is not loop, on is not working, .on is giving error that .on is not a function while i use jquery of 3.2.1

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I've made a fiddle for you: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acdft8cL/)

Comment: i want to use loop because two li elements are there and when an elemt pressed i want to track it

Comment: @AnimeshSahu: If you have multiple selectors then you should include that code in the question.  Currently you have only *one* selector.  There's no need for any loop in the code shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("ul.nav-tabs li" ,"click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
    });
});
```

Comment: i have 3.2.1 jquery bro

Comment: question answered, thanks for interest in this question!! happy coding!

Comment: it throws $this is not defined.... thanks for interest, your answer is not my solution

Comment: it was by mistake u can replace $(this) by "event" it'll work